# How to update repeater field if repeater is locating in the group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying this structure:

Group -> repeater -> sub_field

```
                $value = array(
                    'repeater' => array(

                        array(
                            'repeater_field' => (foreach)$names

                        )
                    ) 

                );

                update_sub_field( $group_name, $value, $post_id );
```

Comment: Are you using acf?

Comment: Yep, advanced custom fields Pro

Answer (score 0):

You get the repeater as a sub_field of the group field and loop it as a repeater.

read about the [update_sub_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) if you are outside of the post if you need the post id.

```
if( have_rows('group') ):
            while( have_rows('group') ) :
                the_row();
                if( have_rows('repeater') ):
                    while( have_rows('repeater') ) :
                        the_row();
                        $value = update_sub_field('sub_field', "update text");
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            endwhile;
        endif;
```

Comment: Send me how did you organize the acf in admin.